# FindDistribution[] with error bars? (And a ChiSquared Question)

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I've got some data defined as follows:

`geigerData={466,471,500,442,469,448,481,470,486,472,446,487,454,485,453,447,488,454,523,478,461,473,472,466,458,463,451,455,465,488,488,413,448,453,438,453,452,505,471,467,471,469,508,469,487,472,430,479,473,475,481,468,482,459,460,478,478,472,447,471,469,431,444,485,453,480,469,462,460,485,497,493,524,491,447,483,478,441,455,475,460,429,468,471,468,479,503,482,495,463,479,504,463,459,492,482,459,476,506,464,453,467,491,448,458,444,456,429,477,473,477,451,483,468,463,464,442,469,449,460,455,466,492,493,462,478,461,529,462,461,461,457,460,494,473,503,462,475,487,467,478,455,449,462,445,462,461,456,441,458,450,465,452,464,474,460,478,439,447,428,468,476,445,476,439,533,481,436,476,477,491,462,454,472,484,465,459,497,485,467,457,462,481,475,489,466,462,455,440,446,479,444,480,465,455,486,506,471,494,429}`

I am trying to fit Gaussian (Title Normal in Mathematica) and Poisson fits to this data. FindDistribution[] appears to be what I'm looking for:

`FindDistribution[geigerData,1,All,TargetFunctions->{NormalDistribution}]`

This gives me 0.96 for ChiSquare, which is one of two values I'm looking for to talk about the goodness-of-fit. However, I have two questions:

1. The Documentation states that "PearsonChiSquare" gives "PearsonChiSquareTest p-value." Does that mean that what it gives me is the value for ChiSquare or is it the corresponding p-value? I need both, but I can't tell what's been given to me.
2. My data is supposed to have error bars. If I was making a list plot, this would be as easy as:

`x_i +- Sqrt(x_i)`

Where the Sqrt(x_i) is the margin of error for the data given by a derivation that's not the focus of this post. I would iterate over the list to create a new one with this equation for each point. But when I do this, while it's supported by ListPlot, FindDistribution gives me an error:

`Argument (insert list data here) at position 1 does not have the right format. Data should be a numerical array of depth.`

Is there another way I can define a list with error that will work with this equation? NonLinearFit has Error -> that can be used, but I don't see that option here.

All help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Have you seen this post?  https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2020806.  Also, you want to fit a probability distribution from a random sample from that distribution.  That makes `NonlinearModelFit` inappropriate for your objective.

Comment: Yes. This is why I am trying to use FindDistribution[], as stated in my post. I am trying to get it to work with data  weighted with error. This is something I know for certain that NonlinearModelFit does, but I can't figure it out with FinDistribution[]. This is why I made my post.

Also, the post you linked to was also me. Nobody had responded to it so I tried my luck elsewhere.

Comment: There's no need to "weight" the data.  (Are you getting that idea from a class instructor?)  It is true that if you have a single observation AND assume you have a Poisson distribution, then the square root of the count can estimate the standard deviation.  But that doesn't mean your count has measurement error.  Are you expecting more than Poisson variability where there really is an error in the count?

Comment: Yes. We recorded this data in class, there is going to be error in the number of counts. It increases with N, being Sqrt(N). It's not just an idea from the instructor; it's a requirement.

Comment: Unless, of course, I am just extremely confused. Honestly, I've been at this assignment for so long I wouldn't be surprised if I missed something huge.

Comment: I’ll write up an answer tomorrow that I hope to convince you otherwise.  There are certainly deviations from the mean count but those deviations are not considered errors.  Now if there is some additional error from the true count, then you have a generalized linear mixed model and *Mathematica* does not have any functions for such models. You’d need to use R or SAS.

Comment: You can do errorbars with the new function `Around` that you can use to tag data with error margins.

Comment: You can also look up the details of the PearsonChiSquareTest p value on the documentation page of `PearsonChiSquareTest` (which is what `FindDistribution` uses to calculate it).

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Do you think that the usual Chisquare test requires or even accepts error bars?  If one is fitting data hypothesized to come from a Poisson distribution including the square root of the count as a weight makes no sense.

Comment: I have no idea, but I honestly don't have a lot of faith in most frequentist black-magic tests like that in the first place.

Comment: @sjoerdsmit I don't disagree about the "faith" issue, but the frequentist approach certainly does not use the square root of the count as a weight.

Answer (score 4):

To obtain what *Mathematica* uses as a Chisquare test for testing if data comes from a Poisson distribution, then the following will work for your data?

```
geigerData = {466, 471, 500, 442, 469, 448, 481, 470, 486, 472, 446, 
   487, 454, 485, 453, 447, 488, 454, 523, 478, 461, 473, 472, 466, 
   458, 463, 451, 455, 465, 488, 488, 413, 448, 453, 438, 453, 452, 
   505, 471, 467, 471, 469, 508, 469, 487, 472, 430, 479, 473, 475, 
   481, 468, 482, 459, 460, 478, 478, 472, 447, 471, 469, 431, 444, 
   485, 453, 480, 469, 462, 460, 485, 497, 493, 524, 491, 447, 483, 
   478, 441, 455, 475, 460, 429, 468, 471, 468, 479, 503, 482, 495, 
   463, 479, 504, 463, 459, 492, 482, 459, 476, 506, 464, 453, 467, 
   491, 448, 458, 444, 456, 429, 477, 473, 477, 451, 483, 468, 463, 
   464, 442, 469, 449, 460, 455, 466, 492, 493, 462, 478, 461, 529, 
   462, 461, 461, 457, 460, 494, 473, 503, 462, 475, 487, 467, 478, 
   455, 449, 462, 445, 462, 461, 456, 441, 458, 450, 465, 452, 464, 
   474, 460, 478, 439, 447, 428, 468, 476, 445, 476, 439, 533, 481, 
   436, 476, 477, 491, 462, 454, 472, 484, 465, 459, 497, 485, 467, 
   457, 462, 481, 475, 489, 466, 462, 455, 440, 446, 479, 444, 480, 
   465, 455, 486, 506, 471, 494, 429};

PearsonChiSquareTest[geigerData, PoissonDistribution[λ], "TestDataTable"]
```

[image: Chisquare table]

Here is how to duplicate (essentially duplicate rather than exactly duplicate) what *Mathematica* does using brute force:

```
(* Get expected counts with approximately equal proportions in each bin *)
nBins = 17
bins = {-1, Table[InverseCDF[PoissonDistribution[mean], i/17], {i, 16}], ∞} // Flatten
(* {-1, 435, 443, 448, 453, 456, 460, 463, 466, 470, 473, 476, 480, 484, 488, 494, 502, ∞} *)
n = Length[geigerData]
(* 200 *)
expected = n*Table[CDF[PoissonDistribution[mean], bins[[i + 1]]] - 
    CDF[PoissonDistribution[mean], bins[[i]]], {i, nBins}]
(* {12.8004, 12.4428, 11.0582, 13.623, 9.29103, 13.4504, 10.6759, 10.9689,
    14.7215, 10.8412, 10.4493, 13.0259, 11.6982, 10.1644, 12.2187, 11.0108,
    11.5594} *)

(* Observed counts *)
observed = Table[Length[Select[geigerData, bins[[i]] < # <= bins[[i + 1]] &]], {i, 17}]
(* {7, 9, 14, 12, 11, 15, 18, 11, 16, 15, 9, 16, 10, 12, 10, 4, 11} *)

(* Chisquare statistic *)
chisq = Total[(observed - expected)^2/expected]
(* 18.1329 *)

(* P-value *)
pvalue = 1 - CDF[ChiSquareDistribution[17 - 2], chisq]
(* 0.255744 *)
```

To test to see if the data could have been generated by a Poisson distribution (with unknown mean), there is absolutely no need to use the square root of the count as a weight.  If you have a reference to such a procedure, I'd really like to see it.

**Addition:**

It seems like you need to examine different numbers of bins.  Here's the above code modified to look at 4 to 20 bins testing for a normal distribution with your data.  (This is not how one determines an optimal number of bins.  You'd first need to state what is meant by "optimal".)

```
results = ConstantArray[{0, 0, 0}, 17];
Do[
 mean = Mean[geigerData] // N;
 stdev = StandardDeviation[geigerData] // N;
 bins = {-∞, Table[InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[mean, stdev], i/nBins],
     {i, nBins - 1}], ∞} // Flatten;
 
 n = Length[geigerData];
 expected = n*Table[CDF[NormalDistribution[mean, stdev], bins[[i + 1]]] - 
     CDF[NormalDistribution[mean, stdev], bins[[i]]], {i, nBins}];
 
 (* Observed counts *)
 observed = Table[Length[Select[geigerData, bins[[i]] < # <= bins[[i + 1]] &]], {i, nBins}];
 
 (* Chisquare statistic *)
 chisq = Total[(observed - expected)^2/expected];
 
 (* P-value *)
 pvalue = 1 - CDF[ChiSquareDistribution[nBins - 3], chisq];
 
 results[[nBins - 3]] = {nBins, chisq, pvalue},
 {nBins, 4, 20}]

TableForm[results, TableHeadings -> {None, {"# of bins", 
"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(χ\), \(2\)]\) statistic", 
"P-value"}}]
```

[image: Statistics from different numbers of bins]

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to set the bin count of PearsonChiSquaredTest[]?

Comment: I'm not aware of anyway to change the bin count for `PearsonChiSquareTest`.  If it's any consolation, the bin count increases with sample size (as it really should) and can be approximated with the formula `Round[2.23117 n^0.385798]`.  But the above code gets the same results and you can pick any number of bins that you want.

Comment: If I were to use the code above for other types of distributions, such as the Normal and Binomial, would I only need to adjust the distribution used in the beginning and then the degrees of freedom at the end?

Comment: My answer would be "Yes" with a slight hesitation.  As you've hinted at the degrees of freedom would be the number of bins minus 1 for matching the total and 1 for every parameter estimated.  The "slight hesitation" is that the example data clearly isn't normal as the data is all integers.  My professional bias/opinion is testing for any distribution is not very useful.  One is usually looking either for a reasonable approximation (estimation rather than hypothesis testing) or looking for gross departures from a distribution.

Comment: Would this work if both expected and actual were both in probability form?

Comment: Absolutely not.  Observed (actual) must be counts with the expected being the expected counts.  Lots of folks do wrongly plug in expected probabilities and observed proportions.  That loses the effect of sample size and the statistic no longer has even an approximate chisquare distribution.  You might ask that question on stats.stackexhange.com.  You'll get the same answer there.

Comment: Damn, that sucks. I am having difficulties replicating the same values using a Gaussian distribution with your data. If only changing bin sizes wasn't a requirement by my professor - I'm supposed to demonstrate what bin sizes are most optimal via a chart.

Comment: My data??  You mean "my code" ?  I'll add in some code for looping through 4 to 20 bins.  I have no idea why you think that you (or your professor) thinks that from a single dataset one can determine an optimal number of bins.  You'd need to define what you mean by "optimal".

Comment: Yeah sorry, your code. Changing the bin number is going to change chi^2 and the degrees of freedom. The right combination of these can maximize the p-value, which would indicate the "optimal number of bins." Here's exactly what my professor wrote:
"For  your  data  set  with  the  largest  number  of  measurements,  plot  the  results  as  a  function  of  bin width. Which bin width gives the best value of reduced chi^2 and corresponding p-value?" The results being chi^2 and p-value. Normally, we would solve for chi^2 through reduced chi^2, but I think mathematica skips that step.

Comment: You need a new professor.  I assume (hope) that this class is not in a Statistics Department. The "reduced chisquare" is used in a regression setting and is NOT for goodness-of-fit for fitting distributions.  Get thyself a better statistics class.